# NMAKE fatal error and pyflann fails to find flann.dll when installing FLANN on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, cmake, nmake, flann

I'm having trouble getting FLANN working on my system. It appeared to install ok but when I tried to call it using pyflann I get the error: `ImportError: Cannot load dynamic library. Did you compile FLANN?`

The only thing that I didn't notice at first was that when I called nmake it didn't work. This was the output:

```
C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

I'm at a complete loss at to what's going on here - can anyone suggest what the problem might be? Does nmake need parameters passing and if so what are they? If so, there's nothing in [the manual](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf) to say so.

**Edited to add:**

The first step to getting further is to select the nmake generator as suggested by @drescherjm in the comments. The command provided by the developer is:

```
cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles"
```

Followed by:

```
nmake install
```

This runs through a load of installation messages and appears to be successful. However when running the test snippet for pyflann given in the FLANN manual, it gives the same error `ImportError: Cannot load dynamic library. Did you compile FLANN?`

The dll is exactly where pyflann is looking for it in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyflann\lib` but it doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Did you select the nmake generator when you configured flann with cmake? Also its best to run cmake inside the Visual Stdio command prompt. Did you try that?

Comment: Having emailed the developer, I used `cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles"` followed by `nmake install` and this gets to the point where everything looks correct. However I still have an error when calling it from Python. I'm now trying again in the VS prompt and will report back if it's solved.

Comment: Edited question with the results of running as Administrator from the VS prompt. Still no joy.